# Handle errors C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, methods

So, I have a simple library-class and this class has some methods that return some values like code errors.

**User_program**

```
MyClass go(arg1, arg2)
if(go.execute() == 0)
  std::cout << go.result();
```

And my class has something like this

**My class**

```
int execute()
{

    if((temp = doBar()) != 0)
    {
         return temp;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

int doBar()
{
   if(foo == 1)
      return DIVIDION_BY_ZERO;
   if(fzz == 0)
      return OPERATION_ERROR;
}
```

And so on. So, is there any method to make errors more helpful, I've heard about enum with const for errors, but I don't understand how to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: There are _so_ many questions about this. Did you read any of them?

Comment: Well, I've read about try-catch, but I don't think that it is a good idea. I've tried to google something like "enum errors C++", but I did find nothing useful. I've looked through project's sources on github and noticed this feature - using enums in this case, but I don't remember where I've found it.

Comment: there are websites dedicated to such things.. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions), [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf). P.S. nothing is a good idea, unless you know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Just look to your right. The "related" section is chocked full of the same question and that's just for starters!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I understood the question right, but here is few moments.

1. In your case enum`s is way to store all definitions of const
   values like (SUCCESS, DIVIDION_BY_ZERO, etc) in one place (even in
   one translation unit). And also compiletime validation of types.
   read more here:
   [[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)
2. 2) If intresting how implemented some error check there is no need
       to go far.

   - First of all look at C handling errors in libc [[2]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno)
   - In ISO C++11 presented [[system_error]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error)
   - And typical error handling in libs released special for (almost) each type like in Qt [[QNetworkReply]](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/network/access/qnetworkreply.h)
3. And also using exceptions(and dark side of C++ like RTTI) in libs is bad idea. But take this link too [[3]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/)